# Progress block with GET and AFNetworking 3.0 is not called

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking-3

I have created a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager`:

```
class TBNetworkClient: AFHTTPSessionManager {
    func wordsWithCompletionBlock(completionBlock: TBErrorHandler) {

        queryType = .Words
        GET("words", parameters: nil, progress: { progress in

            print("----------") //this is not called at all, why?

            }, success: { sessionDataTask, response in

                completionBlock(nil) //success is called

            }) { sessionDataTask, error in

                completionBlock(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Marked line is not called at all, why?

This is the definition above method in source code:

```
public func GET(URLString: String, parameters: AnyObject?, progress downloadProgress: ((NSProgress) -> Void)?, success: ((NSURLSessionDataTask, AnyObject?) -> Void)?, failure: ((NSURLSessionDataTask?, NSError) -> Void)?) -> NSURLSessionDataTask?
```

There is also a note:

> @param progress A block object to be executed when the download progress is updated. Note this **block is called on the session queue**, not the main queue.

When I print `print((sessionDataTask.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.allHeaderFields)`

The output is following:

> Optional([Server: Apache, Connection: Keep-Alive, Content-Type: text/html, Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 08:58:18 GMT, Content-Encoding: gzip, Keep-Alive: timeout=1, max=100, Content-Length: 5663, Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent])

Comment: As far as I can tell, the progress parameter is not a closure, it accepts an `NSProgress` object

Comment: no, it was reference to NSProgress in AFNetworking 2.0, not in 3.0

Comment: This is the source code for that function from AFNetworking 3: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m#L112-L117

Comment: This is not the latest AFNetworking. I updated the question. You can check this now,

Comment: Ah my mistake, I misread the source. Does the server send a `Content-Length` header?

Comment: @chedabob this is why I asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34662763/2725435. Just make me sure. Will it work only when content-length header is set?

Comment: @chedabob what does it mean, that "block is called on the session queue"?

Comment: It means it'll be executed on the queue that the download is taking place on. It's shouldn't be an issue, it just means you won't be able to update the UI (`print` will work fine)

Comment: @chedabob I updated the question. Can you look at this?  There is `Content-Length` in headers but progress block is still not called. Maybe there is sth wrong with other headers?