# How to ensure that my response from server has `Content-Length` header with PHP?

Tags: php

This is how I response from my server:

```
include('../connection.php');
connection();
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

$response = array();
$words = array();


$query = "SELECT * FROM `$table` ORDER BY `created_at` DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $row['id'] = intval($row['id']);
    array_push($words, $row);
}

$response['words'] = $words;

echo json_encode($response);
```

But I really need here `Content-Length` header. How can I check or add/create such header?

Answer (score 0):

PHP handles this for you if you enable output buffeting. When you write to the output stream (via the buffer) PHP knows how much you've written and sets the header value before sending the response body.

Comment: How can I check if it is there indeed?

Comment: Call `phpinfo()` and check the settings. I believe it's on by default.